# Different content for different domain extensions

Tags: seo, domains, multiple-domains

let's say I have `myawesomewebsite.com` on which I have a blog website.
Then I would like to buy `myawesomewebsite.consulting` on which I would put a website for my media agency.

In few words: those are totally different websites with different content but with the same domain name.

Does this affect SEO in any way?

Answer (score 5):

It does not. They're seen as entirely different sites as their domain names *are* different.

Domain names only tend to affect SEO when the name itself contains a keyword. Being similar or the same as another site would allow me to register bbc.consulting and gain a boost from being related to bbc.co.uk